# Laravel - Sum of pivot table results given a criteria

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

**Scenario**
An alert can have many criterias, and many criterias can have my alerts.

A user is assigned to a criteria. When a user views all of their `criteria`, I want it to show the sum of how many matching alerts there are (stored in the pivot table). The relationship uses a pivot table structured as:

[image: Screenshot]

So for example, I can access the alert and criteria data, and it should also tell me that for `criteria_id = 73`, there is one alert match `id_2`.

So the `Eloquent` formula is currently:

```
public function getIndex()
    {
        $alerts = Criteria::with('coordinate', 'alerts')
        ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->get();

        $this->layout->content = View::make('users.alert.index', 
            array('alerts' => $alerts));
    }
```

**Relationship within Alert model**

```
public function criterias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Criteria')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Relationship within Criteria model**

```
public function alerts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Alert')->withTimestamps();
}
```

If you require any further information, please let me know. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to count all alerts or just unique alerts for that criteria?

Comment: There could be multiple criteria associated with that user. So it would need to be "count all alerts associated to each criteria that belongs to that one user", if that makes sense?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973095/getting-count-from-pivot-table-in-laravel-eloquent#25973237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question by using @JarekTkaczyk's example above.

[Getting count from pivot table in laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973095/getting-count-from-pivot-table-in-laravel-eloquent#25973237)