# Join database and count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to list informations about a table and one of that information is how much cars an user has. I have two databases, one is `users` and the other is `cars`. The table `cars` has a column that is `owner` that holds the `id` of the owner. What I want to know is: How to list all users and along with that the total of cars that each user has?

```
$users = Users::all();
```

This code returns an array with all users, what I want is to pass the total of cars that each user has on the same `$users` variable. How can I do that? Is there a way to join the other table, count and then return or something like that?

@edit

I tried like this, but doesn't work:

```
$users = Users::join('cars', 'cars.owner', '=', 'users.id')->select(DB::raw('count(cars.car_id) as total'))->get();
```

Comment: But `->count()` is just for a single query, I want to know of each user.

Comment: Do you have a pivot table setup?

Comment: What you mean with a pivot table setup?

Comment: Are you trying to display them in your view ? (Blade). I can give you the exact syntax.

Comment: Yes, I'm. What is your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the group by statemant:

```
select users.name, count(*) as counter from users 
join cars on ... group by users.name;
```

Okay here in more Detail:

You have to join the users table with the cars table. You do that, yes.

Then you have to select one col from the user table and one count(*) as counter

The trick is now, to "group by" the col from the users table. That matches all double user rows to one row and count how much cars one user has

The select statement is:

"select users.id, count(*) as counter from Users join Cars on cars.owner=users.id group by users.id"

Thats all ... hope that help you

Comment: @MrAlmighty. Take a look at  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973095/getting-count-from-pivot-table-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: @Tobi - `$users = Users::select(DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))->join('cars', 'cars.owner', '=', 'user.id')->groupBy('users.id')->get();` - I tried that way and it's returning only the 'counter' and I need the other columns as well.

Comment: I fixed that way: `$users = Users::select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))->join('cars', 'cars.owner', '=', 'user.id')->groupBy('users.id')->get();`

Comment: I have another problem now... I need to know how many places sells those cars based on the id of the current car. I tried that way: `$users = Users::select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))->join('cars', 'cars.owner', '=', 'user.id')->join('places', 'places.car', '=', 'cars.id')->groupBy('users.id')->get();` - And it's returning only `1` always.

Comment: And another problem I found now is that if the `users` doesn't have a car registered it doesn't return the user.

Comment: Yes you need for that a other join statement.

Comment: I don't understand. The Full Outer Join is to fix the problem of listing the user even if there's no car registered for him? Or the problem of to count the places that has the car based on the the id of the car?

Comment: it was for that problem, that you dont get a user, when he hasnt a car...the other problem i havnt seen ... i dont know if i get that problem...you want to know, how many places are connected with one car?

Comment: Yes, for example. I want to list all users, and along with that I want to know how many cars that user has and how many places has the same car. And list like that: `User X has N cars that sells in N places.` - This mean that the places will be counted by the ids of the cars.

Comment: or has a car exact one "place" as a number?

Comment: in that way its impossible i think, because you want to know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66682/discussion-between-mr-almighty-and-tobi-klostermair).

Comment: 1. how many cars have a user and 2. which places are connected with one car ... you cant connect that two things, that re two querys

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you...

```
Users::with([
              'cars' => function($q){
                           $q->select([DB::raw("count(car_id) as total"), "car_id"])
                             ->groupBy('car_id');
                        }
           ])->get();
```

Comment: This one was made, but now how to know how much places sells the cars that the user has? - Check out the chat (you are there) - Tobi posted a query and I'm having a really bad headache trying to convert to Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this SQL query in raw. I tried and it works.

```
SELECT users.name as User_Name, COUNT(cars.user_id) as Car_Count
FROM users
LEFT JOIN cars
ON users.id=cars.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works, I know, but I have another problem that is: Now I have in the same query to know in how many places sells the cars the user has. For example, The user ´John Stacey` has 3 cars, imagine that each car has a brand and each car sells in one place, then we have 3 places that sells. More or less like this. The listing must to be like that: The user X has N cars that sells in N places.